# how to make parallax demo with three tab like image give below

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to make parallax demo with three tab like image given  below in iOS make scrolling vertically.and click on tab multiple table scrolling Horizental.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by image given below ?

Comment: wait m adding screenshot

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tnltN.png plz check this image i want to make this

Answer (score 0):

Try using a UIScrollView with paging enabled. Then connect an IBAction to the buttons with a tag value to it. The tag value indicates which page the UIScrollView has to show. Make sure the UIScrollView direction is set to horizontal. In this example I'm only adding UIViews but this could be anything. UITableView, UIScrollView or UICollectionView you name it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//Set number of pages
   int numberOfPages = 3;

//Set properties scrollView
   self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true;
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((numberOfPages * self.scrollView.frame.size.width), self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

//Add pages
   UIView *pageOne = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((0 * self.scrollView.frame.size.width), 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
   [pageOne setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
   [self.scrollView addSubview:pageOne];

   UIView *pageTwo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((1 * self.scrollView.frame.size.width), 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
   [pageTwo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
  [self.scrollView addSubview:pageTwo];

   UIView *pageThree = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((2 * self.scrollView.frame.size.width), 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
   [pageThree setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
   [self.scrollView addSubview:pageThree];
}

- (IBAction)btnSelectPage:(id)sender; {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((self.scrollView.frame.size.width * btn.tag), 0) animated:true];
}
```

And for the storyboard do something like this:
[image: Storyboard layout]

Don't forget to set the tag value of the button indicating what page you would like to show.
[image]

Comment: m using this typ of demo bt its not scrolling vertically.i need when m scrolling vertically than make heder multiple tab

Comment: As I mentioned before you need to replace the UIView with a vertical scrolling view. So insert a UITableView with multiple rows. This is exactly the solution you're looking for.

Comment: If this helped you please note this as the answer.